Physical and non-physical
Suppose for a moment that there is no other life in the universe.
If we then would eradicate all life from the face of the Earth, would there be anything non-physical left in the universe?
Physical is to be understood as fermions and bosons (the elementary particles) and the four forces of nature.
Anything?

If you're a physicalist then there's always no non-physical things in the universe even if there're life in the universe, if you're a panpsychist then there's always non-physical neutral monistic psychic things in the universe even if there're no conscious life in the universe...

Please define physical, life, and the philosophical framework you want to apply to the question. As written, everything from "nothing" to "everything" to "category error" would be reasonable answers.

@gs I don't understand your comment. Please, define please, is it a wish, a command, a hidden rebuke? And what do you mean with define? How can we define anything adequately and how can anything have any meaning? And if we cannot define anything adequately, then how can I understand what that philosophical framework is what you are asking about?

Why would the non-physical be in this universe, rather than outside of it?

@tkruse If it would be outside the universe it could have no effect on anyhting in the universe. If it would have an effect on anything in the universe, it then would be by definition in the universe. I take anything that has no effect on anything in the universe as non-existent.

"If it would have an effect on anything in the universe, it then would be by definition in the universe" - by what definition?

I checked a couple of definitions and it generally states something like the totality of all that exists.  If something has an effect on anything in the totality of all that exists, then it is part of all that exists.

Why do we need to eradicate all life on Earth? According to physicalists, there is nothing non-physical to it anyway. According to non-physicalists, non-physical substances and/or properties are there with or without life on Earth, spirits, proto-psychic states, platonic ideas, etc. Let's spare our poor planet.

@Conifold Okay, I'll call the guys to stop the experiment. My question was meant to get that cleared up.  Often the physical here is opposed to the mental and I want to question what is left of the mental without there being any minds to hide in.

What you seem to be asking is whether anything considered non-physical in any branch of philosophy has the property of being associated with life, so that in a hypothetical absence of life, all philosophers would agree that what remained was physical. The answer is no. For example, some thinkers consider abstractions such as numbers and shapes to have been discovered by human minds rather than invented by them.

And may I ask what you think? You think that in lifeless universe with dead planets circling countless stars while being bombarded with cosmic radiation, that there exists a number 13 somewhere?

My view is that numbers, like words, are the product of the human mind. However, they correspond to attributes of the universe outside our minds. In the universe there might be objects circulating round some star, and those objects might be what we would call 13 in number. The thirteen-ness of those objects remains regardless of whether there is a mind to give it that label.

So you would say that thirteen-ness is something non-physical that exists in the universe?

No, I would not use those words at all, precisely because 'non-physical' and 'exists' are such vague words. Take the idea of relative size. In the universe there are objects bigger than other objects. The objects posses those relative attributes. That's as far as you need go. if you go beyond that and say that the abstract concept of bigger therefore exists separately in the Universe, then you are taking an unnecessary step and one that leads to confusion.

Agree. I think I wanted to point out that confusion . Thanks for your answer.  That was very helpful!

Going through my comments, I realise it sounds a bit interrogatively.  I apologise. I really appreciate your feedback!

No problem! I am a very genial soul in reality but like to adopt a slightly grumpy persona on Philosophy SE because I like writing in that tone of voice, so feel free to reciprocate !

Standard Philosophy-101 dilemma:

If a tree falls in an uninhabited virgin forest, does it make a sound?

This is a conundrum because it latches on a polysemy around make-a-sound. To wit:

If sound refers to physics, it obviously does whether or not a hearer exists.
If sound implies a sentient auditory experience, no sentience entails no sound.

In the same way, for one it would make no difference. For the other, no sentient/ sapient being implies not just no physical/non-physical dichotomy, but no universe at all.
The choice is cogently presented by Lukacs  ironically a marxist!
Note 1 — Your language:

If we then would eradicate all life from the face of the Earth...

It's great you've not hidden behind passive voice — If life were eradicated...
So now: What kind of entity is denoted by "we"?

It can be God(ish)
Or non-living
Or "we" have failed in the eradication

Note 2 — Idealism
There is good reason why Berkeley-Idealism is considered serious philosophy, unlike say solipsism...

Question: I'd love you to expand on that: How can idealism work without life, that is, without mind? Genuinely curious.

Note: I shall prefer subvenes under to the more usual supervenes over
Speaking a bit simplistically:

Materialism = matter subvenes under all else
Idealism = X subvenes under all else
Note: I use X to stand for one of {ideation (Berkeley), cogito (Descartes), εἶδος (Plato, typically mistranslated as "form") Hegel((absolute) spirit), consciousness (Vedanta)...}

So far the 2 views are absolutely symmetric. In fact they are a mathematical dual in the sense that we get from one to the other by simply flipping matter(ism) and idea(ism).
However on digging further, the idealist has the upper hand.
An extended comparison
Conversation with a physicalist

Q: What is this?
A: The voltmeter. It's showing 5 V.
Q: Which means?
A: Electricity is electrons. It flows along insultated copper wires...
Q: I dont grok all these terms — electron, copper, insulation...
A: Ah! I shall initiate you into the physicalist gospel. Copper is an element... atoms. It has atomic number 29, atomic weight 63.5. Everything comes down to these 104 elements of which copper is the 29th. Isnt it beautiful??
Q: Uhh if you say so. So what is the atomic number of electron?
A: Aha. You gotchaed me! Electrons are more fundamental than atoms.
Q: So everything's electrons ultimately??

You can continue round and round on the merry-go-round — bosons, fermions, strings, quantum, fields. Or stop! — hearing the chuckle of Herr Munchhausen!
Now compare:
Conversation with an idealist

Q: What is this?
A: People will say it's a voltmeter; showing 5 V. Just add that it's a thought in your head (or mine or whoseever) of a voltmeter showing 5 volts

You can stop here. Or go all the way — just one more step:

A:... And the thoughts exist in me because I am

Asymmetry of Physicalism Idealism
The physicalist has infinite regress whereas the idealist has a hard stop in 1 or 2 steps
Notes:

Yahweh in Hebrew and atma in Sanskrit mean roughly I-AM. A link across the traditions.
...in the head?? Yeah that's a metonymy. The head is (trivially) in the mind. The mind is (very very non trivially) associated with activities in the head. For the idealist the 1st inclusion suffices
Berkeley's slogan: Esse est percipi — to be is to be perceived — is a reminder to the ineluctable fact that whenever we say something is, there is a blip in a sapient head (sorry mind) that something is.
How much mess has been created by Descartes inverting the obvious I am therefore I think into I think therefore I am is incalculable

I'm being ironic above but only slightly.
The real issue is not whether matter subvenes under ideation or vice versa.
The real issue is that Christianity subvenes under all (western) science, philosophy, etc for the last 1000 or more years.
If I were talking to a Vedantist we would broadly agree that the primary subvener is consciousness (= God). And the world is His illusion (maya).
The Buddhist would be more empirical and blunt: Do these fantastic confabulations solve the universal problems of disease, decrepitude, death?
I guess the Taoist would sound sweeter, Zen blunter but they'd all be quite direct
A Peek at an inherently idealist tradition
The tradition of Vedanta carries Berkeley to its logical conclusions:

You say Jupiter is out there billions of miles away. Yet its only in your mind. Go to sleep. Is it still there? So your waking-state being contains the whole physical universe. And your 3 (waking dream sleep) states contains everything — Ramana Maharshi paraphrased


What is matter? Its the boundary where knowing stops — Nisargadatta Maharaj paraphrased

Which gives this alternative to the standard physialist reading:
I hit my head on the wall. That my head is hurt indicates that there is a wall out there that hurt my head — physicalist interpretation.
I hit my head on the wall.  My head hurts — that's the incontrovertible fact. That there is a wall that »did it to me« is an inference — a waking state inference. No such in deep sleep. And alternate realities in dream where we fly, walk on water etc.
End note
Before you jump and ask (as you asked Prof Sushing) Are you an idealist? Seriously?? please read this

To comment

Comment: Need to process this though. I came across Bernardo Kastrup and find it hard to understand. I already struggle with dualism but Idealism is just the world upside down

Karstrup is good and more accessible than earlier idealists like Berkeley, Hegel etc.
However the real point to get re. idealism is that it's not motivated via the intellectual/cognitive path but the personal/affective one.
Questions like

Why do I suffer?
What will happen on my death?
What is the meaning of meaning?
Who/what is God?
«Choose your question»

Materialism was always inadequate for such. And in the 20th century, logical positivism reduced all such to meaningless language games.
Idealism may not answer such but it at least provides a ground where such are permissible and tolerated.
If you get that for idealism to make sense, you stop trying for it to make sense but rather to shock you emotionally out of your ordinary consciousness, here are (my very personal) recommendations:

Illusions by Richard Bach
On having no head by Douglas Harding
Nisargadatta Maharaj
All is One


Re Note 2: I'd love you to expand on that: How can idealism work without life, that is, without mind? Genuinely curious.

@Philomath Not quite sure what direction of expansion you want. But I have added to that section

@Philomath - You should have a look at Pierce's philosophy (Charles Pierce - mathematician, logician, one of the founders of pragmatism and the first developer of semiotics). He talks about "minds" and "quasi-minds" in a way that makes scientific sense. One of the unfortunate developments in 20th century philosophy is that the Fregean school with its Platonist tendencies came to dominate analytic philosophy rather than the work of Pierce.

@Rushi Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this. Hugely appreciated! Need to process this though. I came across Bernardo Kastrup and find it hard to understand.  I already struggle with dualism but Idealism is just the world upside down. Thanks again for the write up!

@mudskipper Dankewel, skipper, I will look it up!

[Yahweh in Hebrew and Allah in Arabic mean I-am] both of these are false. I think you need to find a more reliable source.

@gs tnx.  I've added a yahweh link. And corrected the atma link

@gs A current discussion at Biblical Hermeneutics — posted after the above exchange!
